# Set Equals * in one criterion in Excel AVERAGEIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is a generic version of the formula we are working with:

```
=AVERAGEIFS ( [Average Range] , Active_User, = TRUE, START_YEAR, [Cell A1] )
```

In Cell A1, we want to allow the user to select a specific year (2016,15,14) as well as select ANY Year (*).

Is there a string can we put into Cell A1 that will function as a wildcard?

We've tried * ; "" ; "20*" - also tried changing the fixed reference to something like "="&[A1] or ">="&[A1]. All return Div#0

Realize that this can be done by dropping the START_YEAR criterion from the formula, but we would like to avoid using VBA to modify the formulas. This is in a table with multiple similar AVERAGEIFS so there would be many items to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like `">1900"`? This would look for any date after 1900, which should cover all eventualities... assuming you're not analyzing 19th century events.

Comment: This approach works - I've added an additional constraint `=AVERAGEIFS ( [Average Range] , Active_User, = TRUE, START_YEAR, ">="& [Cell A1], START_YEAR , "<" [Cell B1] )` where B1 is either the next year for a real year or 2100 for the Wildcard value.

Comment: That's a good idea, though I think you might have forgotten a & `"<"&[CellB1]`

Comment: That's correct - typo in my S.O. post. Corrected in my active platform. Thanks for the quick assist.